# Exiting asynctask midway through doinBackground on conditional

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm loading data from async task. In the `doinBackground()`, I want to check if the JSON string returned contains an error, if so I want to stop the AsyncTask and display a textview, if there's no error, I want to continue executing the asynctask. This is my code.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_all_open_bets);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            post.setHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36");
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"));
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
                JSONObject jObj = null;
                String json = "";
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                        if (!line.startsWith("<", 0)) {
                            if (!line.startsWith("(", 0)) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                    json = json.substring(json.indexOf('{'));
                    if (json.contains("error")) {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nobetstxtbox);
                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    Log.d("sb", json);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                // try parse the string to a JSON object
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                // return JSON String
                Log.d("json", jObj.toString());
                try {
                    allgames = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_BET);
                    Log.d("allgames", allgames.toString());
                    ArrayList<BetDatabaseSaver> listofbets = new ArrayList<>();
                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < allgames.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = allgames.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);
                        String returns = c.getString(TAG_RETURNS);
                        String stake = c.getString(TAG_STAKE);
                        String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                        String Teams = c.getString(TAG_TEAMS);
                        Log.d("id", id);
                        Log.d("user", user);
                        Log.d("returns", returns);
                        Log.d("stake", stake);
                        Log.d("status", status);
                        Log.d("teams", Teams);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_TEAMS, Teams);
                        map.put(TAG_USER, user);
                        map.put(TAG_RETURNS, returns);
                        map.put(TAG_STAKE, stake);
                        map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                        useroutcomes.put(id.substring(0, 10), Teams);
                        boolean contains = false;
                        for (int a = 0; a < listwriter.size(); a++) {
                            if (listwriter.get(a).getId().equals(id)) {
                                listwriter.add(a, new BetDisplayer(user, id, Integer.parseInt(stake), Integer.parseInt(returns), status, "", "", Teams));
                                contains = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!(contains)) {
                            listwriter.add(i, new BetDisplayer(user, id, Integer.parseInt(stake), Integer.parseInt(returns), status, "", "", Teams));
                        }


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        bet.add(map);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }


            return "";
        }
```

I added this fragment

```
` if (json.contains("error")) {
     TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nobetstxtbox);
     textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }`
```

to check for the error, but I'm not sure how to exit the asynctask at this point if the error is true and not carry out any of the code after this statement. Using else won't work as it will interfere with the try catch statement, using break also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `cancel()` method in your if condition, calling `cancel()` in `doInBackground()` will cancel your `AsyncTask` and `onCancelled()` will be called instead of `onPostExecute()`

Like this:

```
 if (json.contains("error")) {
       cancel(true);
       return "";  
 }
```

Comment: Yep works fine, you also have to add the `if (isCancelled())` conditional and `return ""` inside that conditional, couldn't get it to work any other way for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in your `doInBackground()`:

```
if (json.contains("error")) {
    return "error";
}
```

And in your `onPostExecute()`

```
void onPostExecute(String message)
{
    if(message.equals("error"))
    {
         //You cannot access UI thread in doInBackground(). So, you need to do all the UI related tasks over here.
         TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nobetstxtbox);
         textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    else
    {
        //your code for the positive results
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put a return statement in your conditional, which will exit the method in the same manner as it would exit any method (in this case it will exit to the onPostExecute() method).

Comment: So you suggest I add `return ""`? I still need it to bypass the onpostexecute method though

Comment: Sounds like the cancel(true) is the way to do this (I didn't know this).

Answer (score 0):

You can call `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)`

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

See this question [Usage of mayInterruptIfRunning to cancel ASyncTask - Function call order -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569752/usage-of-mayinterruptifrunning-to-cancel-asynctask-function-call-order)

on how to use the mayInterruptIfRunning flag.